# $\lim_{n \to \infty }\int_{0}^{n^{1/3}}(1-\frac{x^{2}}{n})^{n}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

How to compute the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty }\int_{0}^{n^{1/3}}(1-\frac{x^{2}}{n})^{n}dx$. The question asks an answer in the form of a definite integral.

Comment: Show us your thoughts/progress on this problem.

Comment: I just thought $(1-\frac{x^{2}}{n})^{n}$ part can be $e^{-x^{2}}$, but this is obviously not rigious. Then I try $(1-\frac{x^{2}}{n})^{n}=e^{n\log{(1-\frac{x^{2}}{n})}}$ and expand log as series, but it seems doesn't work.

Comment: Can you argue that $
\log \left( {1 - \frac{{x^2 }}{n}} \right) \le  - \frac{{x^2 }}{n}
$ for all $n>0$? (i.e., $\log(1-w)\leq -w$ for all $w>0$) Also, do you know the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: As @Gary has pointed out, DCT allows one to find the answer. Note that $(1-\frac{x^2}{n})^n$ is monotone increasing, converging to $e^{-x^2}$ pointwise.

Comment: Does DCT here permit to conclude that the limit is always the same, substituting n^1/3 with any function f(n) going to infinity for n large ?

Comment: @Thomas I imagine if $f(n)$ is too large (on the order of $\sqrt{n}$), the integral diverges to $-\infty$ for odd $n$, and $+\infty$ for even $n$, but for 'small' $f(n)$ your observation holds.

Answer (score 3):

As you pointed out, this limit should ring a bell
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \Big( 1 - \frac{a}{n}\Big)^n = e^{-a}
$$

So a natural candidate is $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx$.
Now, we need to make sure that this is actually the case, to do so, we need
to control the error between the two expressions.

First, we write
$$
\int_0^{n^{1/3}} \Big(1 - \frac{x^2}{n} \Big)^n \frac{e^{-x^2}}{e^{-x^2}} dx
$$
which can be written as
$$
\int_0^{n^{1/3}}  e^{-x^2} e^{n\log\Big(1 - \frac{x^2}{n} \Big)+x^2} dx
$$
Remember that the Taylor expansion of $\log(1-z)$ (which is convergent for $|z|<1$) is
$$
\log(1-z)= - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k}.
$$
As $|x|\le n^{1/3}$, we have that $|x^2/n| \le n^{-1/3}$. We will only use the first term together with the Lagrange remainder to get therefore we can prove that
$$
n\log\Big(1 - \frac{x^2}{n} \Big)+x^2
=
-\frac{(y_x)^2}{n},
$$
for some $y_x \in (0,x)$.
Then, we have that
$$
\int_0^{n^{1/3}} \Big(1 - \frac{x^2}{n} \Big)^n dx
= 
\int_0^{n^{1/3}} e^{-x^2} dx
+
\int_0^{n^{1/3}} e^{-x^2} \Big( e^{-y_x^2/n}-1 \Big) dx
$$
We get that the first integral converges to the desired indefinite integral.
Using the Taylor expansion for the  exponential, the second integrand can be
bounded by a constant times
$$
e^{-x^2}\frac{x^2}{n}
$$
Finally, notice that
$$
\int_0^{n^{1/3}} e^{-x^2} \Big( e^{-y_x^2/n}-1 \Big) dx
\longrightarrow 0,
$$
indeed, we have that for any  $n \ge 1$
\begin{align}
\Big|\int_0^{n^{1/3}} e^{-x^2} \Big( e^{-y_x^2/n}-1 \Big) dx \Big| 
& \le
\Big|\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \Big( e^{-y_x^2/n}-1 \Big) dx \Big|
\\ & \le \frac{C}{n}
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} x^2 dx.
\end{align}

As the last integral converges, we get the desired convergence as $n\to \infty$.